# What are the platform common classes in Kotlin?

Tags: javascript, java, android, kotlin, api-design

I'd like to use Kotlin to define interfaces between client and server.

Currently, Kotlin can be used in 3 platforms: Java, Android, Web(JS).

**What Kotlin build-in classes can I use across all these platform?**

I would expect some common library dependency between [kotlin-stdlib](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.1.2-4) and [kotlin-stdlib-js](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-js/1.1.2-4), but couldn't find one.

On the other hand, I managed to create the following interface that can be used on all 3 platforms:

```
interface SomeApi {
    fun update(params: Collection<String>)
}
```

So, how can I figure out what can be used across all platforms, in addition to `Collection`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use all classes in `kotlin-runtime` and `kotlin-stdlib`, especially everything that's in the [stdlib/common](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/stdlib/common/src) folder in the Github repo.

Multiplatform projects are currently in development and once they're released, it should be easier to write platform independent code.

Comment: Except for knowing what can I use, I'd also like for the IDE to prevent me from using an object which isn't in all 3 platforms. This means that `stdlib/common` should probably be a separate artifact which all other depend on. Is there a plan to move the commons to a separate artifact?

Comment: Like I said, multiplatform is on the way, but not available, yet.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka if that answer was helpful to you, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Is the multi-platform project developed as an open source? If so, can you share a link? Thanks.

Comment: It's all part of the Kotlin project https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin, though it's not exactly trivial to dig through